# Boolean in F# is evaluated wrong

Tags: .net, f#

I have this piece of F# code:

```
let readBytes isVariable (br: BinaryReader) = 
    seq {
        while br.BaseStream.Position < br.BaseStream.Length do
           let c = br.PeekChar()
           if c = 0 && isVariable
               then
                   yield Array.get (br.ReadBytes(2)) 1
               else yield br.ReadByte()
       }

let main argv = 
    let processCopybook = readLines copybookFile
                          |> Seq.map (fun x -> parseElement' x parserList)
                          |> Seq.filter (fun s -> not (s = []))
                          |> Seq.map makeElementFromTokenLine
                          |> makeTree
    let isVariable = isVariableLength processCopybook

    let br = lazy(new BinaryReader(new FileStream(dataFile, FileMode.Open)))

    let bytes = readBytes isVariable br.Value

    if isVariable
       then Seq.takeWhile (fun c -> not (c = byte 0x0A)) bytes |> Seq.toList |> ignore
       else ()
```

When I run this code, no matter the value of isVariable (which is either true or false), it gets into the then clause of the last if statement

However, when I use this piece of code for the if statement:

```
let func = if isVariable
              then fun () -> Seq.takeWhile (fun c -> not (c = byte 0x0A)) bytes |> Seq.toList |> ignore
              else fun () -> ()
```

And then call func(), it is evaluated correctly.

Why is this? It doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: Directly in the main function

Comment: Maybe post a more complete example - I think if something this basic was broken, more people would have noticed.

Comment: What would be good here is a sscce.  See here: http://sscce.org/ - in particular a small script that we can run ourselves.

Comment: what is the value of `bytes` in both cases? Is it mutable? With the latter version, you defer evaluation of `bytes` until you execute it within `func()`

Comment: bytes is a seq<byte>, so it is mutable. I'll try to whip up an sscce today.

Comment: How do you see that it gets into the then clause of the last if statement each time?

Comment: Using the debugger in Visual Studio, and if I inspect the sequence after, it has shifted as it should if the statement was executed

Comment: All effects of the code in question happen as side-effects of using the `bytes` sequence in a discarded computation. Without the definition of `bytes`'s side-effects, this is rather foggy. Is it really *evaluated wrong*? Or just the debugger's indication misleading? Are optimizations enabled and, if so, could they validly erase the code in question? This code style – using `Seq.toList |> ignore` to evaluate an unsuspiciously named value – is odd, and I would expect that this is part of the confusion. (If you really want to keep this, `Seq.iter ignore` would more clearly hints at side-effects.)

Comment: I added the code for the `bytes` value. The reason I do the toList is because if isVariable is true, I need the code to be evaluated and Seq doesn't always do that because of laziness.

Comment: Note that F# debugging experience can sometimes be misleading and it seems you are executing code that is not being executed. Also I think I have noted that F# seems to be optimize code it deem not having side-effects. I would analyze the actual IL code to see what the program is actually doing.

Comment: @FuleSnabel - it is much easier to just add a `printf` than look at IL,